# z-index and anchor tag

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a div with position relative and `z-index :-1`. and I have placed `<A>` over that
div. But it seems `<a>` is not working when i give postion `:relative` to its parent. when change that
position to absolute it starts working. Could anybody tell me why this is happening.
I want that link to work and as far as possible need to keep its parent div 
position `:relative` 
and `z-index:-1;`

Answer (score 4):

`position:relative` will make the z-index relative to the parent.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index

Comment: so why it is disabling my <a> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Negative z-index cause a links to not work:

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rwSw/)